# input shape in ASR training

Tags: python, pytorch, python-3.x, speech-to-text

Sorry for stupid question but can someone say what is the shape of input batch in ASR training? Because as I understood, if we work with spectrogram we got something like

```
[batch, freq_dimension, time_dimension]
```

but in few people's code I've seen that they used input shape as

```
[batch, time_dimension, freq_dimension]
```

What is the right version?